# A scaling functional equation

Tags: generating-functions, functional-equations

I want to find a closed form of a function satisfying

$$G(4z)=\frac{G(z)}{2z},$$

unfortunately I am not experienced with scaling problems, so I have no idea and would be thankful for any hints.

For those interested, the background of this equation is, that it describes the generating function

$$G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$ of the sequence $a_n=2^{n^2}-\delta_{n0}$, for which I need a closed form.

Comment: This series does not converge unless $z=0$. Is there perhaps something missing?

Comment: A generating function is a formal series--its coefficients are used to keep track of numbers.

Comment: As far as I understood, the series of a generating function does not have to converge, it's just a formal arithmetical object, not a function in a strict sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=4^u$ ,

Then $G(4\times4^u)=\dfrac{G(4^u)}{2\times4^u}$

$G(4^{u+1})=\dfrac{G(4^u)}{2\times4^u}$

$G(4^u)=\prod\limits_u\dfrac{1}{2\times4^u}$

$G(4^u)=2^{-u}4^{-\sum\limits_uu}$

$G(4^u)=\Theta(u)2^{-u}4^{-\frac{u(u-1)}{2}}$ , where $\Theta(u)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$G(4^u)=\Theta(u)2^{-u^2}$ , where $\Theta(u)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$G(z)=\Theta(\log_4z)2^{-(\log_4z)^2}$ , where $\Theta(z)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$G(z)=\Theta(\log_4z)2^{-\left(\frac{\log_2z}{2}\right)^2}$ , where $\Theta(z)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$G(z)=\Theta(\log_4z)2^{-\frac{\log_2z^{\log_2z}}{4}}$ , where $\Theta(z)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$G(z)=\Theta(\log_4z)z^{-\frac{\log_2z}{4}}$ , where $\Theta(z)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't it be $u(u+1)/2$ instead of $u(u-1)/2$ in line 6?

Comment: @flonk: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum#Antidifferences_of_rational_functions

Comment: yes, my doubt was not on the indefinite sum, but on the definite. The question is what the limits are. (for example in $1+2+..+u=u(u+1)/2$ you have a plus sign)

Comment: The reason why I ask is, that this $+$ could make your result agree to the answer from @Penguino.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

$G(z) = k z^{\displaystyle{-(1+\ln(z)/\ln(16))}}$

I discovered this by considering how the logs of both sides of the function scale.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I believe your $G$ solves $G(4z)=G(z)/(4z)$ (with a $4$ in the denominator).

Comment: Sorry, I have to correct myself, I think yours is $G(4z)=G(z)/(8z)$.

Comment: Thanks anyhow, the general type of ansatz is exactly what I was looking for! If you correct the formula, I can accept your answer. Also, I don't understand yet, how you found this by "considering how the logs of both sides (..) scale". Could you describe this a bit deeper, so I might learn from your intuition?