# Solution to a general scaling problem $G(\lambda z)=\frac{G(z)}{\gamma z^n}$

Tags: analysis, functions, functional-equations

When playing with the scaling problem

$$G(4z)=\frac{G(z)}{2z}$$

(see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700859/a-scaling-functional-equation/)) I discovered, that the general problem

$$G(\lambda z)=\frac{G(z)}{\gamma z}$$ with two constants $\lambda,\gamma>0$ can be solved by

$$G(z)=kz^{\displaystyle{a+b\ln z}},\qquad a=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\ln\gamma}{\ln\lambda},\qquad b=\frac{-1}{2\ln\lambda}.$$

But how would one approach the more general problem

$$G(\lambda z)=\frac{G(z)}{\gamma z^n}$$ with a free power $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=\lambda^u$ ,

Then $G(\lambda\lambda^u)=\dfrac{G(\lambda^u)}{\gamma(\lambda^u)^n}$

$G(\lambda^{u+1})=\dfrac{G(\lambda^u)}{\gamma\lambda^{nu}}$

$G(\lambda^u)=\prod\limits_u\dfrac{1}{\gamma\lambda^{nu}}$

$G(\lambda^u)=\gamma^{-u}\lambda^{-n\sum\limits_uu}$

$G(\lambda^u)=\Theta(u)\gamma^{-u}\lambda^{-\frac{nu(u-1)}{2}}$ , where $\Theta(u)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$G(z)=\Theta(\log_\lambda z)\gamma^{-\log_\lambda z}\lambda^{-\frac{n(\log_\lambda z-1)\log_\lambda z}{2}}$ , where $\Theta(z)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Comment: How should I interpret $G(\lambda^u)=\prod\limits_u\dfrac{1}{\gamma\lambda^{nu}}$, where $u$ is fixed on the left side, but multiplied over on the right side?